# Dialogflow: following up on quick reply directly to webhook

Tags: dialogflow-es

I am building a simple quiz bot with Dialogflow.

When I detect a "start of quiz", I am able to send a Quick Reply with 3 proposals, thanks to the fulfilment on the Question intent.

However, when the user clicks on one of the proposed answers, I need to have that response back to my backend so I can check the result and finally give a score, for example.

Basically, the "response-check" intent should be automatic right after the quick reply and Dialogflow should not try to understand that response.

Is there any way to easily achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Using "events" you can directly trigger an intent. Or if you are only using Dialogflow console for training, better to have an output context say "check-answer" as an input context to your answer checking intent and use the same "check-answer" as output context to all your questions intent.